# JQuery + creating radiobuttons for html from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I am building a simple quiz to learn javascript...

Here is a simple model of how I want to handle the answers [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vc7Aa/) 
This works for when my Qs&As array is in this format -->

```
allButtons = [["Milk", "Butter", "Cheese"],["Water", "Beer", "Wine"]];
```

I am trying to understand this particular part -->

```
$(allButtons[index]).each(function (i) {
answers += '<input type="radio" name="group1' + '" value="' + allButtons[index][i] + '">' + allButtons[index][i] + '<br>'
});
```

and apply it to this example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HumYx/)  
as this is how I initially have my Qs&As set up where the format of the array is different -->
 `allButtons = [[Questions...][PossibleAnswers...][Answers]]` 
I have given it a go but not successfully

So how do i do the same thing with this different Q&A array format?

PS. I could just change my format, but first I would like to explore this first.

Comment: working version http://jsfiddle.net/HumYx/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why were you using index2 in $.each?

Also it should be [i] for indexing and not {i}

```
$("#up").on("click", function () {
    var answers = '';
    $(allButtons[1][index]).each(function (i) {
        answers += '<input type="radio" name="group1' + '" value="' + allButtons[1][index][i] + '">' + allButtons[1][index][i] + '<br>'
    });

    $("#answers").hide(); //required to show it slowly 
    $("#answers").html(answers); //show my answers 
    $("#answers").show('slow'); //slowly fade in Answers 

    index += 1;

});
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: tks I see my mistake now doh! `$(allButtons[1][index]**[index2]**).each(function (i) {
answers += '<input type="radio" name="group1' + '" value="' + allButtons[1][index]**{i}** + '">' + allButtons[1][index][i] + '<br>'
});`

Answer (score 0):

Just for my reference, and slightly related

trying to get the value of the radio button that was selected here...

http://jsfiddle.net/HumYx/2/ -- this works but I may have to change the way my radio buttons are written to get the right index 
this needs changing

```
$(allButtons[1][index]).each(function (i) {
answers += '<input type="radio" name="group1' + '" value="' + allButtons[1][index][i] + '">' + allButtons[1][index][i] + '<br>'
});
```

changed it to this and it works this is what I want

```
$(allButtons[1][index]).each(function (i) {
answers += '<input type="radio" name="group1' + '" value="' + i + '">' + allButtons[1][index][i] + '<br>'
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HumYx/3/ - note a and b now work the way we want in this format, e nver got to work right, and c and d are from the previous one